# Looking for information and/or how to connect the RF433Mhz module (WL101-341/WL102-341)

Tags: rf

I'm trying to find information about this 433MHz RF module: [QIACHIP](http://www.ozeki.hu/p_6034-information-about-433-mhz-modules.html)

[image]

Apparently it can be connected to an Arduino with the [RadioHead](http://www.airspayce.com/mikem/arduino/RadioHead/) library, but I don't have diagrams of how to connect them togheter in order to send/recieve data, becasue the module have 4 pins (Vcc, Gnd, Dat and En). I guess Dat pin should be connected to any Arduino pin, but as I only have one module I dont wanna risk it. I have no previous experience with RF modules :-(

I have found some [Youtbe](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BmfmnfHpapo) video, but the language of the video is in russian, and I don't know that langauge (I even ask the owner of the chanel for subtitles).

Please, if anyone have worker whit this module before, share:

- How to connect the module with an arduino?
- A simple example of how to send a simple word (let's say: "Hello") from the transmitter to the reciever

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're right not to just go ahead and wire things up. There's a couple of nuances that you need to take into account.

**Transmitter**

- Ignore the EN pin - that does nothing on that module
- The transmitter is 1 3.3V device. You need to power it from the 3.3V pin and use logic level (5V -> 3.3V) translation on the Data pin

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2ffYPRP.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

**Receiver**

The receiver is much simpler as it is a 5V device:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fZ8lzX.png)</sup>

On the Arduino it shouldn't matter what IO pin you use, the Radiohead library should work fine with any of them.  These modules are pretty dumb - you raise DAT high on the TX and DO on the RX goes HIGH. Very simple.

Comment: Thanks! If you would't tell me about the Tx is a 3.3V device I surely would fried it! I think I have a shift converter laying around or could use the VoltageDivider as well. Thanks! I will try now

Comment: Hi @Majenko, I already connect everything as you draw it: Tx on a Nano 3V3 and DAT pin to HIGH (trough a VoltageDivider), Rx on an UNO, but when I read the D0 with the UNO I get only 0. Can you share how to make these Tx and Rx modules comunicate among them? Im trying to get some info, but the RadioHead library doesn't seem to be writen for these modules... It should work tho, cuz the russian guy for the Youtube vid I shared make them work...

Comment: Well, I make it work: I remove the VoltajeDivider and hook up the PIN12 in the NANO directly to the DAT pin on the Tx, using RadioHead library, and Im now able to send data from the Tx to the Rx...